# C# getting empty .txt while using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, file, save, .net

I have a problem with a StreamWriter method of c# system.IO namespace. I would like to save a few lines of data to a .txt file, but the file I'm getting is always empty.

My method:

```
public class Statystyki
{
public void save(string path, Central cent)
        {
            StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(path);
            stream.WriteLine("Something one: "+cent.number1);
            stream.WriteLine("Something two: "+cent.number2);
        }
}
```

my main:

```
Central newcentral = new Central();
Statystyki stats = new Statystyki();
savepath="c:\projects\central.txt";
statsy.save(savepath, newcentral);
```

I've tried many solutions, but no one has worked. What's the problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your  FileStream class ? show your complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that:

```
stream.AutoFlush = true;
```

Comment: Give you 1 point to solve the problem but why this happen? please consider explain your code

Answer (score 2):

It'd be easier to use the `File.WriteAllLines` method (in the static class `File`, also in `System.IO`):

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, 
    new[] { "Something one: "+ cent.number1, "Something two: "+ cent.number2 });
```

It manages all of the possible errors, and the disposing, for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that your string variable is incorrect. In C#, you have to provide double slashes unless you use a verbatim. Here is a quick example I wrote that worked.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\text111.txt"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("something 1");
            writer.WriteLine("something 2");
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete program.Works 100% but console version. Try this and Modify your code according to your need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace book_StreamWriter
{
    class FileWrite
    {
        public void writeData()
        {
           using(FileStream fs =
                new FileStream(@"D:\myfile2.txt",
                                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
           {
              StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
              Console.WriteLine("Enter a string :");
              string str = Console.ReadLine();
              sw.Write(str);
              sw.Flush();
              sw.Close();
           }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileWrite fw = new FileWrite();
            fw.writeData();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of `FileStream` here is not required and as you've wrapped it with `using`, `fs.Close()` is redundant.  `StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable` and should really be wrapped in a `using` statement of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it in a `using` statement so that the stream is flushed and the object is disposed of:

```
using(StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    stream.WriteLine("Something one: "+cent.number1);
    stream.WriteLine("Something two: "+cent.number2);

}
```

as [user3076560](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20448681) has pointed out, your string likely needs to be escaped.  You can accomplish this by the statement:

```
savepath = @"c:\projects\central.txt";
```

or

```
savepath = "c:\\projects\\central.txt";
```

in the main program.

Answer (score 0):

In you main(), you declared `stats` as an object of the `class Statystyki`. But, you are using `statsy` to access your `save()`. So, I'm not sure if your code compiled.
Also, add the `using` statement.